# rabbitmq - Problem recovering queue and resume socket messages

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am having serious problems to make messages delivery fail proof in a chat system.

Having several `node.js` and live communication via `websocket` to the clients, I use `rabbit` to callback the correct consumer at a specific node.

I declare my queues as `{durable: true, prefetch:1, expires: 2*3600*1000, autoDelete: true}`

consumerOption is `{noAck: false, exclusive: false}`

Once I receive a message from the server, I callback the server, get the message, and use `message.ack(false)`

Sometimes, a message appears with a pendent ACK in rabbit and as I would expect, the consumers stop being callbacked.

Here is my overall strategy:

1- when socket disconnects, I recover the queue using `queue.recover()` during the the reconnection/connection (more frequent).

2- When I send a message to the server and not receive it back, I send a message to the server to recover the queue.

3- I use the socket callback function to send the ack confirmation. On the server, I use `message.ack(false)` The server keeps a hashmap `{[ackCode: string]: RabbitMessage}` and I send the ackCode back to the server, so it can retrieve the correct message and ack it.

5- If client is not receiving any message for 2 minutes, I ask to the server to recover the queue.

The step 5 should not exist but even with this step, sometimes I send a recover queue request to the server, the server executes the command, but nothing happens and chat is freeze.

These are very difficult events to debug. I am using a Typescript [library](https://github.com/abreits/amqp-ts) which is 3 year without any commit and this could be one of the causes.

Regarding the strategy, is it correct? Any idea on what I could be facing?

Comment: Something this complicated requires code to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What I've learned and why I think that I couldn't use `rabbit` to solve the specific problem mentioned in the original post.

**The domain:** A "chat" where the message order is very important (some are chains) and we must be sure that the message will be delivery if/when the client is online.

**The problem:** We have several node.js servers, sockets are spread among them. Sockets falls all time, and it is common to a client connection that was in the first server be connected again in another. We don't use cookies, session affinity by IP won't handle the issue.

**Limitations:** That being said, I can't activate a consumer that is currently activated in another server, so if a customer Queue is tied to server 1 I can't activate it in server 2. And all the messages that need to be sent are tied to this specific queue.

Another limitation is that I don't have an easy way to consume queues, re-queue, to know in advance how much not `ack` messages I have in the queue, aggregate them and bulk send them via socket.

**The solution:** I am no longer using `{noAck: false}` and I am controlling the ack in a Redis queue. Thus, I am using Rabbit as a pub-sub, to callback the correct consumers to send the message using the socket. Rabbit wake me up, first thing I do is to put the message at the end of a redis queue. When I send a message via socket, I always start sending the messages from the beginning of the queue, regardless of the message that have just woke me up. I send the message, wait for the callback event, If it is not ok, I re-queue the messages,

After decoupling the pub-sub from the `queue/ack` control, I can now easily change my rabbit pub/sub from one server to another (declaring using `socket.id` and no more with the client queue), with no concern of loosing any message. Also, now I am capable of much more advanced operations on my queue.

As my use case don't allow me to use the full power of exchanges/binds (i have complex routing rules), I am evaluating the possibility of changing from rabbit to redis pub/sub, but in this case, I would continue to differentiate pub/sub from the queue.

After more than a month trying to make rabbit working in this scenery, I think that I was using a good technology to the wrong use case. It is much simpler now.